# Airport attached devices easy move to another location

Tags: macos, ios, time-capsule, airport

Let's say I have multiple apple devices connected to wifi via an airport. I would like to move to another location and there only have to re-configure airport. Keeping the wifi pass as it was before.

I wouldn't go to each device and re-configure wifi settings.

I tried that with an airport express 1st gen without success.

Does the new line with simultaneous dual-band support help on the issue?

May be this could be called kind of private own wifi.

Comment: So let's say you're moving to a new house. If you unplug the ethernet cable in the old house, move everything to the new house, and plug the new ethernet cable in, all of the settings for the airport should have remained the same. Does this answer your question/is this what you were asking? If not, could you please clarify by editing your question?

Comment: Instead of using the ethernet cable in the new place, let's say I would be using an already available wifi as internet source. And I would like to have my own private wifi, is that feasible?

Comment: I don’t believe so... you can use the airport as a “bridge”, but then it just acts like a repeater - it doesn’t make its own network.

Comment: And using the guest network feature... Would it be possible to join an existing wifi and create a guest one for my own devices?

Comment: It’ll work only if you create the guest network on the main router, not the extender you have

Comment: So, one way to do what I'm saying perhaps will be to use two airports... The first to such wifi and offer it over ethernet port (join network) and other in bridge mode, connected by cable to the first one, to have my own network. Does it make sense?